# HTML5 download website as PDF

Tags: javascript, html, pdf

I've read [here](http://webreflection.blogspot.de/2011/08/html5-how-to-create-downloads-on-fly.html) that every html website can be saved as PDF.

This is exactly what a i need. 
I need to create a "Download to PDF" button that saves the current website to PDF.

Watching the code in that website understand that to save the website as pdf i need to construct every element in the website using javascript?

Can't i simply point to "/ticket.html" as save it as a PDF?

```
function createPDFLink(fileName) {
    var doc = new pdf();
    // whatever content you want to download
    var a = document.createElement("a");
    a.download = fileName;
    a.title = "download as PDF";
    a.href = doc.output('datauri',{"fileName":name});
    return a;
}

// some paragraph in the page
document.querySelector(
    "p.saveaspdf"
).appendChild(createPDFLink(
    "document-" + document.title + ".pdf"
));
```

Comment: The blog post you reference links to the actual instructions for creating PDF from JavaScript. Unfortunately, the link is dead and there's no information about that. Thus, that important part "whatever content you want to download" is the actual hard part here.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't save a 'website' to pdf, but it is possible to create a pdf from a 'webpage'.

You can just print a webpage as a pdf or if you want a pdf-button on your site, you can use a 3rd party library. There are server-side libraries and client-side libraries (javascript) for that. Here is an example of such a client-side library: http://mrrio.github.io/jsPDF/